# Laravel Websockets + Lets Encrypt SSL + Nginx

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

Hello I am trying to configure my production server to use laravel web sockets over SSL. I thought I have it properly configured when I am able to connect to Laravel Websocket's dashboard via my production server however I later found out that it only works on my end.

I have found out that on my machine, I cannot connect to my websockets server using Chrome but I can with Firefox.

On other machine Firefox and Chrome won't connect to the websockets server which makes it more confusing.

I am using a Let's Encrypt Cert and here's my configuration

My .env

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=12345
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ABCDEFG
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=HIJKLMNOP
PUSHER_HOST=xxx.xxxxx.xxx
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxxxx.xxx/fullchain.pem
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxxxx.xxx/privkey.pem
```

My broadcasting.php

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

Is it an SSL issue or am I missing out on something?